# Compare a string variable to a list and output to a variable in Mac bash shell

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

Ok, I am extremely a newb at shell script and have only basic knowledge. I tried searching for an answer to my question but was only able to find bits and pieces for what I'm trying to do.

I would like to grab the model number from a mac (any OS but currently we use 10.7.x, 10.8.x, 10.9.x.) compare it to a list (of model numbers) then output that to update the hostname.

The username (we will use jsmith) which has been defined as $USERNAME

The final result would look like this (depending on the machine type):

jsmith-MBP13

or

jsmith-MBP15

The first line in the code returns a result that looks like this:

MacBookPro8,1

Here's the code:

```
MODELID=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Model Identifier" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " ")

MBP132010="MacBookPro8,1"
MBP152010="MacBookPro8,2"
MBP172010="MacBookPro8,3"
MBP132011E="MacBookPro9,1"
MBP152011E="MacBookPro9,2"
MBP172011E="MacBookPro9,3"
MBP132011L="MacBookPro10,1"
MBP152011L="MacBookPro10,2"
MBP172011L="MacBookPro10,3"

for i in $MBP132010 $MBP132011E $MBP132011L; do
[ "$MODELID" = "$i" ]
MBP13=$"MBP13"
done

for i in $MBP152010 $MBP152011E $MBP152011L; do
[ "$MODELID" = "$i" ]
MBP15=$"MBP15"
done

for i in $MBP172010 $MBP172011E $MBP172011L; do
[ "$MODELID" = "$i" ]
MBP17=$"MBP17"
done

sudo scutil --set HostName $USERNAME"-"
sudo scutil --set ComputerName $USERNAME"-"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName $USERNAME"-"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that if the last char of MODELID is 1, then you want "MBP13", etc, so

```
MODELID=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Model Identifier" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " ")

case ${MODELID#*,} in
    1) model=MPB13;;
    2) model=MPB15;;
    3) model=MPB17;;
    *) echo "error: unrecognized model ID: $MODELID"; exit ;;
esac

hostname="${USERNAME}-$model"
```